# Is it possible to convert a TensorFlow iterator reference to a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
$ print(sample_tensor) 

Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(20, 26, 26), dtype=float32)

$ print(type(sample_tensor))

<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

I would like to convert `sample_tensor` into a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simple:

```
sample_eager_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_tensor)
numpy_tensor = sample_eager_tensor.numpy()
```

should do the trick

Comment: it will give the following error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Ok, you are right, you should first cast it to EagerTensor type:
tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_tensor)